# Transplanting vegetable plants

Tags: vegetables, transplanting

I am having to move home and have 3 tomato plants and about 10 sweetcorn in my polytunnel. I also have carrots outside growing

The tomato’s are in flower and the sweetcorn have husks starting to form and my carrots probably need another 10 or so weeks

Is it possible to relocate these and continue to grow them? I wondered about using a large pot for each of the sweetcorn for instance? Where I am moving to I will probably have to leave them in a pot this year as the garden is currently all concrete/paved. The person buying the house has already told me they intend to rip it all out as they don’t garden at all.

Comment: Couldn't hurt to try.

Comment: I agree with @YosefBaskin - give it a go!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tomatoes stand a chance if you get enough roots/dirt.

IME, odds are pretty slim for the corn and carrots. Neither are commonly transplanted and that's because transplanting them is rarely successful. They have extensive roots, but don't make a rootball that will hold together well when digging them out.

But given it's being ripped out, might as well dig as much as you can and take it with you, even if the plants don't make it, you'll have planter or new garden soil.